# How to pass a jquery object to function?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a generic code

```
var rodd = $('#checkBox');
```

I want to pass rodd to a function and check if it is checked

```
Callme(rodd);

$(rodd).click(function() {
Callme(this);
});

function Callme(rodd){
if(this.checked){
// do some behavior
}
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If `rodd` is a jQuery object:

```
function Callme(rodd) {
  if (rodd.is(":checked")) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

or:

```
function Callme(rodd) {
  if (rodd[0].checked) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
//Assuming rodd is a jquery element
Callme(rodd);

rodd.click(function() {
  Callme($(this));
});

function Callme(rodd){
  if(this.is(":checked"){
    // do some behavior
  }
}
```

remember that the event listener has this pointing at the DOM element, not the jquery element. Therefore you need to convert this into a jquery element, using the $(this) expression.

Comment: Your second option steered me in the right direction. I was trying `this.css("cursor", "pointer");` but needed to wrap `this` in a jQuery selector first, `$(this).css("css", "pointer");`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code, your passing in a jQuery object, `rodd`, into a function to return a jQuery object `$(rodd).click...`

It might be easier to do

```
$('#checkBox').click(Callme);

function Callme(rodd){

    if(this.checked){
    // do some behavior
    }

}
```

or

```
$('#checkBox').click(Callme);

function Callme(rodd){

    if($(this).is(':checked')){
    // do some behavior
    }

}
```

this also does away with the anonymous function event handler that is only executing `Callme()` passing in the event target. **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/udiyo)** here.

**EDIT:**

Currently, `Callme(rodd)` above expects a `HTMLElement object` to be passed in. If you want to be able to pass in a jQuery object, simply change to this

```
$('#checkBox').click(function(event) {

Callme($(event.target));

});

function Callme(rodd){

    if(rodd.is(':checked')){
     alert('checked');
    }

}
```

although personally, I would keep it as an element to be passed in and do the wrapping in the `Callme` function. you might want to consider prefixing the `rodd` parameter with `$` to make it obvious that a jQuery object is expected.